# Execute long task in background using Promise

Tags: typescript

In my `angular2` application I have a method which might be taking long time so I'm using `promise` to perform it asynchronously.
I want calculation to be in background so GUI will continue to work as usual but seems like my GUI wait for calculation to be finished.

Method 'func' in service-

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            console.log("2");
            //some long process in database
            console.log("3");
            if(result!=null){
                resolve(result);
            }
            else{
                reject("Failure");
            }
});
```

and I'm using this method from component-

```
   this.service.func().then(data => {
            console.log("4");
   });
   console.log("done");
```

**current output is** - 
2
3
done
4

**desired output** - 
done
2
3
4

what am I missing? how can I execute long task in background using a `promise`?

Answer (score 2):

The content of the Promise is not Async on it self, a promise will ensure that IF there is an async call like an http request it will call the then callback function as soon as resolve is called with some data.
but if you just run a console.log it will run synchronously.
try to run this code to get what you expect:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("2");
          console.log("3");
          resolve();
        }, 0);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is that there is no long running task like a web service call in your promise. So, your Promise resolves immediately, which is why you see the console logs in sequence.

If you want to see the behavior you are looking for, simulate a long running task inside your Promise by using a `setTimeout` like this.

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      // Simulate long running process with 2 second delay
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("2");
        console.log("3");
        resolve();
      }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: What if time goes beyond 2000 ms?

Comment: The delay is there just to simulate an asynchronous process like a web service call. In your code, you will be replacing that with your http calls.

Answer (score 0):

It has been so long since this question is posted but this might help someone.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("2");
  //some long process in database
  console.log("3");
  if (result != null) {
    resolve(result);
  } else {
    reject("Failure");
  }
});
```

current output is -
2
3
done
4

desired output -
done
2
3
4

above code doesn't give the desired output because code inside the promise constructor runs synchronously.

When setImmediate() is used as follows it will print the desired output.
Because when setImmediate() or setTimeout() is used function that is passed as an argument will be placed in the event loop for execution. so that rest of the code gets executed first and only when the task queue in the event loop is free, setImmediate() or setTimeout() will be executed.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log("2");
    //some long process in database
    console.log("3");
    if (result != null) {
      resolve(result);
    } else {
      reject("Failure");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: setImmediate is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate